# Can python fastparquet module read in compressed parquet file?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

Our parquet files are stored in aws S3 bucket and are compressed by SNAPPY. 
I was able to use python fastparquet module to read in the uncompressed version of the parquet file but not the compressed version.

This is the code I am using for uncompressed

```
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key='XESF',    secret='dsfkljsf')
myopen = s3.open
pf = ParquetFile('sample/py_test_snappy/part-r-12423423942834.parquet', open_with=myopen)
df=pf.to_pandas()
```

This return no error but when I am trying to read in the snappy compressed version of the file:

```
pf = ParquetFile('sample/py_test_snappy/part-r-12423423942834.snappy.parquet', open_with=myopen)
```

I got error with to_pandas()

```
df=pf.to_pandas()
```

Error message

> KeyErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 df=pf.to_pandas()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastparquet/api.py in
>   to_pandas(self, columns, categories, filters, index)
>       293                              for (name, v) in views.items()}
>       294                     self.read_row_group(rg, columns, categories, infile=f,
>   --> 295                                         index=index, assign=parts)
>       296                     start += rg.num_rows
>       297         else:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastparquet/api.py in
>   read_row_group(self, rg, columns, categories, infile, index, assign)
>       151         core.read_row_group(
>       152                 infile, rg, columns, categories, self.helper, self.cats,
>   --> 153                 self.selfmade, index=index, assign=assign)
>       154         if ret:
>       155             return df
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastparquet/core.py in
>   read_row_group(file, rg, columns, categories, schema_helper, cats,
>   selfmade, index, assign)
>       300         raise RuntimeError('Going with pre-allocation!')
>       301     read_row_group_arrays(file, rg, columns, categories, schema_helper,
>   --> 302                           cats, selfmade, assign=assign)
>       303 
>       304     for cat in cats:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastparquet/core.py in
>   read_row_group_arrays(file, rg, columns, categories, schema_helper,
>   cats, selfmade, assign)
>       289         read_col(column, schema_helper, file, use_cat=use,
>       290                  selfmade=selfmade, assign=out[name],
>   --> 291                  catdef=out[name+'-catdef'] if use else None)
>       292 
>       293
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastparquet/core.py in
>   read_col(column, schema_helper, infile, use_cat, grab_dict, selfmade,
>   assign, catdef)
>       196     dic = None
>       197     if ph.type == parquet_thrift.PageType.DICTIONARY_PAGE:
>   --> 198         dic = np.array(read_dictionary_page(infile, schema_helper, ph, cmd))
>       199         ph = read_thrift(infile, parquet_thrift.PageHeader)
>       200         dic = convert(dic, se)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastparquet/core.py in
>   read_dictionary_page(file_obj, schema_helper, page_header,
>   column_metadata)
>       152     Consumes data using the plain encoding and returns an array of values.
>       153     """
>   --> 154     raw_bytes = _read_page(file_obj, page_header, column_metadata)
>       155     if column_metadata.type == parquet_thrift.Type.BYTE_ARRAY:
>       156         # no faster way to read variable-length-strings?
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastparquet/core.py in
>   _read_page(file_obj, page_header, column_metadata)
>        28     """Read the data page from the given file-object and convert it to raw, uncompressed bytes (if necessary)."""
>        29     raw_bytes = file_obj.read(page_header.compressed_page_size)
>   ---> 30     raw_bytes = decompress_data(raw_bytes, column_metadata.codec)
>        31 
>        32     assert len(raw_bytes) == page_header.uncompressed_page_size, \
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastparquet/compression.py in
>   decompress_data(data, algorithm)
>        48 def decompress_data(data, algorithm='gzip'):
>        49     if isinstance(algorithm, int):
>   ---> 50         algorithm = rev_map[algorithm]
>        51     if algorithm.upper() not in decompressions:
>        52         raise RuntimeError("Decompression '%s' not available.  Options: %s" %
>
> KeyError: 1

Comment: Could you please show what error you get, and some detail about how the file was produced?

Comment: yes. Sorry about it! ^ see the edit in the post

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error likely indicates that the library for decompressing SNAPPY was not found on your system - although clearly the error message could be clearer!

Depending on your system, the following lines may solve this for you:

```
conda install python-snappy
```

or

```
pip install python-snappy
```

If you are on windows, the build chain may not work, and perhaps you need to install from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-snappy).

Comment: https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/pull/84 to improve the error message.